# htaccess: Handle all requests by index.php except for particular page

Tags: .htaccess

I have an htaccess file that makes all requests to be handled by index.php:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

I want the same behavior except for all requests to myfile.php (including extra query strings like myfile.php?somecontent=1). So all requests that contain myfile.php in the query strings are to be handled by the original file - myfile.php

how do I add such an exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add negative lookahead condition in this rule to skip certain know URI for this rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^(?!(?:index|myfile)\.php$)(.+?)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

`(?!(?:index|myfile)\.php$)` is negative lookahead assertion that skips this rule for `/myfile.php` and `/index.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to add a RewriteCond before your RewriteRule

Simplest way:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ! myfile.php 
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```

There is also a more generic way to exclude all existing files and directory:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} ! -d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/?$ index.php?q=$1 [L]
```